# Is it possible to unpipe an object without a reference to the stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I have a ReadableStream and a WriteableStream. After instantiating both objects I piped the readable stream into the writeable stream.

```
  const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
  const writeable = new WriteableStreamObject();
  readable.pipe(writeable);
```

Is there a way to unpipe the stream without having a reference to the readable stream.

The usual way to go about this of course is to

```
  readable.unpipe(writeable);
```

However in this case I no longer have access to the readable object, only the writeable object. I would like to do something along the lines of

```
  writeable.disconnectAllStreams()
```

The reason I need to do this is that at somepoint I no longer need the writeable and I need to disconnect it from the stream. I can throw away all references in order for it to be garbage collected but without unpiping the stream will happily continue to consume memory forever (the stream is never ending) and because the stream still retains a reference, the object will never get garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

A writable doesn't really know something is piped to it.  It just knows that something regularly writes to it.  It's the readable that keeps track of one or more other streams that it is piped to.  So, there is no built-in way to do:

```
writeable.disconnectAllStreams()
```

because the writeable doesn't actually know who is piped to it.

You could put the readable stream as a reference onto the writable:

```
const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
const writeable = new WriteableStreamObject();

// store readable on the writable so we can unpipe it later
writable.pipeStream = readable;

// set the pipe
readable.pipe(writeable);
```

Then, later you could do:

```
// get the readable and unpipe it
writable.pipeStream.unpipe(writable);
```

Comment: @michaelsutherland - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.